# Command raised an exception: TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to get a line of data from a dictionary and if that line says "null" skip past it and continue the loop.
When I try to do so, I get this error:

`Command raised an exception: TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`

Here is my code:

```
        card = requests.get('https://api.scryfall.com/cards/named?fuzzy=' + search)
        prints = requests.get(card.json()['prints_search_uri'])

        for i in prints.json()['data']:
            if prints.json()[i]['prices']['usd'] == 'null':
                continue
            else:
                print(i['set_name'] + ': ' + i['prices']['usd'])
```

I am quite new to Python, and coding in general, and I haven't found an answer that I understand.
How do I get rid of this error?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean to do just `[i]["prices"]` ?

Comment: Hmm, that error seems to do with the code in the `else` statement, I think `i['set_name']` is set to `None` check the API result and lmk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your problem is here:

```
for i in prints.json()['data']:
    if prints.json()[i]['prices']['usd'] == 'null':
```

The variable "i" is a dict, as can be inferred from the other lines of code where you access some of its values by their keys. Just replace prints.json()[i] with i:

```
for i in prints.json()['data']:
    if i['prices']['usd'] == 'null':
```

Answer (score 0):

In general the error means that the `__hash__` method does not exist on the key type for the `dict()` in question.

For example:

```
  class Hashable:
      def __hash__(self): 
       return self.some_string
```

The `Hashable` type can be used as a key in a dictionary.

A `dict()` will always call `__hash__` for the underlying key.

Now for your case, it seems weird that you are iterating over a list from `prints.json()["data"`] storing that in `i` and then using that to index into `prints.json()` it seems unrelated...

In any case I think that is where your error is, because it is evident that you `i` is a `dict` type and you are using that as a key in `prints.json()` which is also a `dict` which is an error as explained above.